# how to extract Json data in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin

How to extract Json data where I don't know the parameters like in this case

```
[
{
id: "binance",
name: "Binance",
year_established: 2017,
country: "Cayman Islands",
description: "",
url: "https://www.binance.com/",
image: "https://assets.coingecko.com/markets/images/52/small/binance.jpg?1519353250",
has_trading_incentive: false,
trust_score: 10,
trust_score_rank: 1,
trade_volume_24h_btc: 1101704.8108077163,
trade_volume_24h_btc_normalized: 1101704.8108077163
},]
```

Although I created a data class but I am unable to use it in [ fun getExchanges(): Call<Crypto> ]

```
package com.example.cryptotracker

data class Crypto (
    val name:String,
    val country:String,
    val url:String,
    val image:String,
    val trade_volume_24h_btc:String,
    val trade_volume_24h_btc_normalized:String

    )
```

Here I extracted Json data in a different App using the following Data classes.

```
package com.example.news2

 data class News (
     val totalResults:Int,
     val articles: List<Articles>
  )
```

```
package com.example.news2

data class Articles (

    val author:String,
    val title:String,
    val description:String,
    val url:String,
    val urlToImage:String

   )
```

```
{
status: "ok",
totalResults: 70,
-articles: [
{
source: {
id: null,
name: "CNBC"
},
author: "Eustance Huang",
title: "Electric vehicles need to be owned longer, driven further to offset 'embedded carbon,' Jefferies says - CNBC",
description: "Jefferies' Simon Powell says a "huge amount" of carbon is emitted when materials like steel and aluminum are created and put together for vehicle manufacturing.",
url: "https://www.cnbc.com/2021/05/27/jefferies-on-the-carbon-challenges-in-electric-vehicle-manufacturing.html",
urlToImage: "https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/106880053-1620412523089-gettyimages-1232464403-EVGo_005_04222021JPG.jpeg?v=1622013741",
publishedAt: "2021-05-27T01:16:00Z",
content: "Electric vehicle manufacturing currently faces an "embedded carbon" challenge, says Jefferies' Simon Powell. "To gain the environmental dividend that governments are looking for, users are going to … [+2028 chars]"
} ]
```

Comment: What is your exact requirement? you want to parse the json?

Comment: yes! I want to parse Json array?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to decode an array of `Crypto`s objects in JSON format you could use the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library:

```
val cryptoJsonArray = [
    {
        id: "binance",
        name: "Binance",
        year_established: 2017,
        country: "Cayman Islands",
        description: "",
        url: "https://www.binance.com/",
        image: "https://assets.coingecko.com/markets/images/52/small/binance.jpg?1519353250",
        has_trading_incentive: false,
        trust_score: 10,
        trust_score_rank: 1,
        trade_volume_24h_btc: 1101704.8108077163,
        trade_volume_24h_btc_normalized: 1101704.8108077163
    }
]

val cryptoArrayType = object : TypeToken<List<Crypto>>() {}.type
val cryptoList = Gson().fromJson<List<Crypto>>(cryptoJsonArray, cryptoArrayType)
```